# To show if function $f(x), 0\leq x<\infty$ is convex then $a_{n}=f(n)$ is convex sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

How can we show that if the function $y=f(x)$ is convex in $0\leq x<\infty$, then the points $a_{n}=f(n)$ form a convex sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it true that $$f(n+1)\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(f(n)+f(n+2)\right)\,\,?$$Hint: take $\,\,x_1:=n\,\,,\,x_2:=n+2\,$ and apply convexity of $f$:$$f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x_1)+f(x_2)\right)$$

Comment: Yes it is true.

Comment: There...instead of $\,f(n)\,$ and etc. put $\,a_n\,$ and etc. and you get the definition of convex sequence...:)

Comment: A function f is said to be convex on $(a,b)$ if $$ f(tx_{1}+(1-t)x_{2})\leq tf(x_{1})+(1-t)f(y_{1})$$, where $0<t<1$ and $x,y\in (a,b)$.  As you say if we take $x_{1}=n, x_{2}=n+2$ and take $t=\frac{1}{2}$, we get, $$ f(\frac{1}{2}n+(1-\frac{1}{2})(n+2))\leq \frac{1}{2}f(n)+(1-\frac{1}{2}f(n+2)$$ $$\therefore f(n+1) \leq \frac{1}{2}(f(n)+f(n+2))$$. So i think i show what you suggest. So from this what we say?

Comment: Do what I wrote in my last comment...and read carefully and understand the definition of *convex sequence*

Comment: A sequence $(a_{n})$ is said to be convex sequence if $(\Delta a_{n})$ is decreasing or $\Delta^{2}a_{n}\geq 0, \forall n\geq 0$. It means $$\Delta^{2} a_{n}\geq 0$$ $$\Rightarrow a_{n+1}\leq \frac{1}{2}(a_{n}+a_{n+2})$$ Am i right?

Comment: Yup, exactly that.

Comment: Thanku so much! And it means to write the proof of given result i have to show first$$ f(n+1)\leq \frac{1}{2}(f(n)+f(n+2)).$$